# How to change just the x position in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to make a very simple non-scrolling platformer and I am having trouble with the movement. I have a variable (xspd) and would like to change the x position of a sprite (or node or whatever it is called) but I cannot include the variable inside the CGVectorMake  brackets. This is the code with the problem:

```
        alien.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(xspd, 0))
```

The part after the "CGVectorMake" is the part with the problem. It says that you cannot use a double in a CGFloat value. (The xspd variable is a double) Can someone please help? It would be great for me to either know a way to only move the x axis by the variable or find out how to convert a double into a CGFloat value.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert those parameters from `Double` to `CGFloat`.

```
alien.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(CGFloat(xspd), CGFloat(0.0)))
```

Comment: No need to do `CGFloat(0.0)`, `0` is enough there as `CGFloat` conforms to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`. Also, it's suggested to use the initialiser over the `*Make` function. So: `alien.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: CGFloat(xspd), dy: 0))`

Comment: (I would like to upvote but I cannot because I am new)